# Span of a set of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, vector-spaces

> Does the set of matrices
>
> $$\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}1 &-1 \\ 0&2 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} -1&2 \\ 3&-4 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0&0 \\ 1&0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 2&-2 \\ 1&4 \end{bmatrix}\right\} $$
>
> span the vector space M$_{2,2}$? Justify your answer.

Can someone please review my solution? Here is my solution:

Using the correspondence

$$\begin{bmatrix} a&b \\ c&d \end{bmatrix} \leftrightarrow (a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{R^4}$$

we can if check that the matrices are linearly independent:

The matrices are only linearly independent $\iff$ the corresponding vectors (1,-1,0,2), (-1,2,3,-4), (0,0,1,0) and (2,-2,1,4) are linearly independent.

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0&2 \\ -1&2&0&-2 \\ 0 &3&1&1 \\ 2&-4&0&4 \end{bmatrix} \sim 
\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1&0&2 \\ 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&3&1&1 \\ 0&-2&0&0 \end{bmatrix}
\sim
\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0&2 \\ 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&1 \\ 0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

matrix rank = 3 while the number of vectors =4 $\Rightarrow$ the vectors are linearly dependent in $\mathbb{R^4}$

$\Rightarrow$  the matrices are linearly dependent in $M_{2,2}$
$\Rightarrow$ the set of matrices does not span $M_{2,2}$

Comment: Note that the tag I added...

Comment: This is a sound method. Barring possible numerical error it must be correct.

Comment: thank you for adding tags and checking my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would accept that argument. No errors that I see.

Comment: Thank you for checking!